# Replacing default repositories with Kubuntu repositories

Tags: kubuntu, repository

recently I have migrated Kubuntu and KDE and removed everything related to Gnome (with some exceptions of course). I've read some and learnt that Kubuntu has its own repositories. So, what I wonder is in what manner I have to change my repository list. I mean which part of my list should be discarded and which parts should be kept. Here is my sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubuntu has the **same official repositories** as regular Ubuntu. No changes are needed. If you want to add unsupported PPAs for "bleeding edge" KDE packages, those are additional and at your own risk.

Comment: So, should I add those or not? https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa

Comment: If you are unsatisfied with the versions of the packages in the default repos, maybe...

Comment: Without removing any entry from my sources.list?

Comment: Yes, you use the separate `add-apt-repository` command to add/remove PPAs.

Comment: One last question bit then: Do the packages in Kubuntu repos includes "improvements" for programs to work better in Kubuntu/KDE?

Comment: No, just "newer" versions as they are released by the KDE team. These will gradually make their way into Official Ubuntu repos too after testing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as *izx* said, you shouldn't remove any repositories and Kubuntu has the same core packages available as Ubuntu, but different ones installed.

However, one of the first things I do in a new install of Kubuntu is adding [`ppa:kubuntu-ppa/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ppa), because the official repositories don't push new KDE versions... I recommend it to you as well; I never had problems with it, because new KDE versions get properly tested there too.

[`ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports) may also be worth adding when a new version of Ubuntu is released and you use an older one and don't want to upgrade. This repository will keep getting new KDE versions while the `.../ppa` one will get quiet and move on to the next version of Ubuntu.